# Is the certificate for primality testing polynomial in the length of the input?

Tags: np

If we were to assume that primality testing was in NP.

What would the certificate be, so that a polynomial time verifier can check the number X is indeed prime?

Comment: We don't need to assume anything since primality testing is in $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}$.

Comment: If we had to assume that primality testing was in **NP**, that would mean that we didn't know if it was or not. Since knowing a certificate would prove that it's in **NP**, your question doesn't make much sense: it's essentially, "Assuming we knew how to solve this problem, how would we solve it?" The only reason you have answers is that, fortunately, you chose a problem that we do know how to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before it was proven that primality is in P, it was known that a complete factorisation if n-1 could be used to prove primality of n.  Now this also requires a proof that all factors in the claimed factorisation are actually themselves primes; this leads to a O(n^2) size certificate.

Google for “Pratt certificate”.

(When you use a certificate to solve a problem in NP, you cannot just “trust” the certificate. So if I tell you “here is a complete factorisation if n-1”, you can’t just believe that. You’d have to check that the product of the factors is actually n-1, which is easy. But you’d also have to check that each of the numbers that I claim are prime factors are actually prime, so you need a certificate for primality of these smaller numbers as well)..

Answer (score 2):

The $\mathsf{PRIMES}$ problem [is in $\mathsf{P}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), so it can be decided by a TM in polynomial time. This means that *any certificate* suffices, in particular even the empty string, since the verifier (which is a poly-time TM) can simply ignore the certificate and check membership directly.

Comment: Several [primality certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate) were known prior to the AKS test. This might be more insightful than just saying "primes is in P".